# deactivate facebook page migration

Tags: facebook, api, migration

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#21) Page ID 113815235360719 was migrated to page ID 129553623789646.  Please update your API calls to the new ID",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

One Of our admin of Page I Love nepali football( id 113815235360719 ) migrated this page to his page without knowing us... so can we get back our fan page??